# SANE stack and Passportjs

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am using the [sane stack](http://sanestack.com/) and I would like to add [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) to it.

I successfully implemented passportjs in a sails application using the  instructions [here](https://github.com/sails101/even-more-passport).  I am trying to use those instruction to add passportjs to a sane application.  I am also considering trying to have sails serve the login, logout, ect... pages, since the those instructions use sails' views.  This might not be the best decision going forward, but right now I just want something that works.

I have been getting the following error when I go to login.

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
server   |  TypeError: undefined is not a function
server   |     at Object.AuthController.login (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/api/controllers/AuthController.js:50:9)
server   |     at bound (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
server   |     at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
server   |     at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
server   |     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
server   |     at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
server   |     at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
server   |     at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
server   |     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
server   |     at /Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/api/policies/passport.js:32:7
server   |     at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:318:9)
server   |     at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:67:10)
server   |     at attempt (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
server   |     at authenticate (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
server   |     at /Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/api/policies/passport.js:28:23
server   |     at initialize (/Users/someUser/Documents/sanestack/project/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:62:5) [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

The problem is with following code in server/api/controllers/AuthController.js

```
 33   login: function (req, res) {
 34     var strategies = sails.config.passport
 35       , providers  = {};
 36
 37     // Get a list of available providers for use in your templates.
 38     Object.keys(strategies).forEach(function (key) {
 39       if (key === 'local') {
 40         return;
 41       }
 42
 43       providers[key] = {
 44         name: strategies[key].name
 45       , slug: key
 46       };
 47     });
 48
 49     // Render the `auth/login.ext` view
 50     res.view({
 51       providers : providers
 52     , errors    : req.flash('error')
 53     });
 54   },
```

And also the following code in /server/api/policies/passport.js

```
 24 module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
 25   // Initialize Passport
 26   passport.initialize()(req, res, function () {
 27     // Use the built-in sessions
 28     passport.session()(req, res, function () {
 29       // Make the user available throughout the frontend
 30       res.locals.user = req.user;
 31
 32       next();
 33     });
 34   });
 35 };
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: and, which one is line 50?

Comment: I added the line numbers.  Line 50 was for AuthController.js

Comment: so, `res.view` doesn't exist. Not sure why that would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are running into this problem, because you are trying to use Sails server views and the Sane stack expects Ember to handle all the views... If you look at https://github.com/mgenev/how-to-sane you will see the client/server auth interaction there and how the 2 play along, it's not passport based and it has some work pending, but you can get the general picture

Comment: I tried that link earlier.  I was not able to get everything working.  When I did the `sane up`, I got many errors.  Things like `Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'` and `17:10  error  Expected indentation of 10 characters            indent` and a whole lot more.  Maybe I will do a post on that one as well.  In any event, I will look at the code and see if I can make something of it.  Thanks.

Comment: oh, ignore those errors, i added a linter a few days ago and haven't had a chance to clear them. about Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app', I think you need to run 'npm install' in the client folder and then 'bower install' there, and also npm install in /server

Comment: Thanks!  Your advice worked for getting the project up and running.  I see you have Passport - User Authentication in the additional tools.  Are you planning to implement passport in this project?

Comment: I had it and then found it redundant, but may be adding it back if I switch to sails-permissions, haven't decided yet

Comment: So I searched your repo, for passport and checkout the commit right before the you removed passport.  I 'bower install' and 'npm install' the client and 'npm install' the server.  When I `sane up`, I get the following errors: `Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string`.  I would add the whole stack trace but it will not fit in the comments (at least with out multiple comments.)  It seems to be broccoli stuff.  Your current code works and I may end up using it.  But the reason I am trying to use passport is so I do not have to 'maintain' the auth myself after it is configured.

Comment: if you have further questions you should come to the chat https://gitter.im/artificialio/sane

Comment: I would, but I have to speak to my repo group admins because of the organization access before I can use that site.  Until they handle that issue,  I will be posting on stackoverflow.   I have posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903501/how-does-the-sane-stack-represent-parent-child-relationships-on-a-single-model).  You seem to be pretty knowledge about the SANE stack so any help with this other question would be greatly appreciated as well.  Thanks.