# How does the SANE stack represent parent/child relationships on a single model

Tags: ember.js, orm, sails.js, relationship, waterline

How do I represent a parent/child relationship on the same model?

An example of this is a model representing a folder.  A parent folder can have many children folders.  But a child folder can only have one parent folder.

Ember.js has the concept of [reflexive relations](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/defining-models/#toc_reflexive-relation).  I would like to implement the first option.

> "... explicitly define the other side, and set the explicit inverse
>   accordingly ..."

How would I go about setting that up on the sails.js side of the SANE stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what adjustments you would need to make on the client site, however I'm pretty sure the only way to do this on Sails side is to setup a second model that references the same table.

This would allow you to have a table of items that has a one to many relationship on itself.

```
stuffA.js
module.exports = {
   table:'stuff',
   attributes: {
        otherStuff : {
             model: 'modelB'
        }
   }
}

stuffB.js
module.exports = {
   table:'stuff',
   otherstuff: {
         collection : 'stuffA',
         via: 'otherstuff'
   }
}
```

I understand this may NOT answer your question since you asked how you would do this on a single *model*, but in case you you meant single Collection / Table.

Comment: Thanks meeker!  Just seems a bit repetitive.  I used the folder object as an example because it is simple, but my object is a bit more complex.  I will probably create a lookup model that has two attributes, one that references the parent and one that references the child.  Just thought there was some way to do it using one model.

Comment: Your not mistaken in that their should be. Waterline is growing up pretty fast and it will probably be in there before it hits 1.x. This is just how you can do it now.